# Does corr function in DataFrame object return restricted matrix with size 190X190?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, correlation

I have been trying to produce corr matrix based spearman using pandas DataFrame. all the results grant me matrix 190X190 although i inserted 200+ nd.array into the DataFrame object.

```py
import pandas as pd

vectors # list of 200 nd.array with the same size
df = pd.DataFrame(vectors)
mat = df.corr(method="spearman")
print (len(mat))
```

This lines should print 190 while i expected to see 200, does the corr function support only up to 190 elements?

Comment: Nope, printed 200 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pandas.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) method computes the correlations on columns, perhaps your vectors are of length 190 and this is why you are seeing the result.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(200, 10))
df.head()
          0         1         2  ...         7         8         9
0  0.635328  0.801989  0.928792  ...  0.409299  0.500572  0.096176
1  0.849282  0.947163  0.474262  ...  0.693389  0.260647  0.021113
2  0.057634  0.032594  0.576879  ...  0.954159  0.106100  0.265630
3  0.031656  0.114908  0.902100  ...  0.541662  0.560113  0.148045
4  0.904117  0.878109  0.982493  ...  0.416373  0.038374  0.329338

[5 rows x 10 columns]
df.corr()
          0         1         2  ...         7         8         9
0  1.000000  0.158221 -0.027012  ... -0.060187 -0.146682 -0.046548
1  0.158221  1.000000 -0.059599  ...  0.038815 -0.052355 -0.037781
2 -0.027012 -0.059599  1.000000  ...  0.075159  0.015261  0.035054
3 -0.047710 -0.002200 -0.122131  ... -0.060431  0.017568  0.000935
4 -0.029542 -0.036819  0.108064  ... -0.002548 -0.097453 -0.047605
5 -0.007827  0.026060  0.078727  ...  0.009858  0.076280  0.031792
6  0.107026  0.109253 -0.094501  ... -0.069312 -0.045408 -0.103385
7 -0.060187  0.038815  0.075159  ...  1.000000  0.036394  0.028998
8 -0.146682 -0.052355  0.015261  ...  0.036394  1.000000  0.157691
9 -0.046548 -0.037781  0.035054  ...  0.028998  0.157691  1.000000

[10 rows x 10 columns]
# Note 10 x 10 output as we calculated correlation between columns
df.T.corr()
          0         1         2    ...       197       198       199
0    1.000000  0.498877 -0.365548  ...  0.332607 -0.334024 -0.167504
1    0.498877  1.000000 -0.206066  ... -0.202328  0.212138 -0.265470
2   -0.365548 -0.206066  1.000000  ...  0.220807 -0.363419  0.006970
3    0.161274 -0.030202  0.350527  ...  0.242371 -0.124993 -0.419660
4    0.413043  0.360164  0.085686  ...  0.299763 -0.057072 -0.354378
5   -0.178747  0.398373  0.122139  ... -0.364762  0.298731  0.096835
6    0.428633  0.332952  0.206733  ...  0.504151 -0.489508 -0.530162
7    0.031738  0.178856  0.671928  ...  0.140511 -0.077814 -0.450641
8   -0.082514  0.217348 -0.263754  ...  0.037616  0.382671  0.078891
9    0.003956 -0.037507 -0.071405  ...  0.416418 -0.364057 -0.422265
10   0.477660 -0.062398 -0.223941  ...  0.052904 -0.005123  0.232310
11   0.064510  0.322448  0.112256  ...  0.037528 -0.122080 -0.149634
12  -0.097806  0.338672 -0.546019  ... -0.220268  0.306534  0.068144
13  -0.031138  0.213664 -0.397962  ...  0.188932  0.180403 -0.378188
14   0.038888 -0.024346  0.238451  ...  0.425915 -0.181613 -0.562234
15   0.465428  0.260079 -0.572854  ... -0.080576  0.082298 -0.261606
16  -0.535678 -0.257890  0.514151  ... -0.259198 -0.053499  0.268481
17   0.308875 -0.186421 -0.391446  ...  0.360044 -0.158955  0.268429
18  -0.275178  0.155606 -0.347488  ... -0.047829  0.533397 -0.412796
19   0.080700  0.391280  0.418628  ...  0.388697 -0.248641 -0.417406
20  -0.423705 -0.664545  0.227255  ...  0.245131 -0.463002  0.577954
21   0.853115  0.356033 -0.445827  ...  0.471394 -0.404416 -0.273944
22   0.307765 -0.038106  0.022683  ...  0.470156 -0.174377 -0.516724
23   0.618258  0.708506 -0.450709  ... -0.002726  0.290722 -0.410717
24   0.469414  0.757931 -0.550096  ... -0.370019  0.310175  0.131973
25  -0.308645  0.494687 -0.153664  ... -0.533062  0.496228 -0.040558
26   0.242789  0.687153 -0.506575  ... -0.448844  0.358878  0.133408
27  -0.069875 -0.473316  0.138600  ...  0.489610 -0.095459  0.139735
28   0.155511  0.238704  0.102230  ...  0.338030 -0.073523  0.182840
29  -0.112128 -0.138975 -0.060637  ... -0.028259 -0.349001  0.490552
..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
170  0.226813  0.031162 -0.205408  ... -0.613621  0.117084  0.357222
171  0.451682  0.491021 -0.474939  ...  0.372531 -0.272856  0.008240
172  0.158155 -0.228592 -0.352837  ... -0.118192  0.223844  0.010163
173  0.450049  0.319076  0.158477  ...  0.245050 -0.308017 -0.241448
174  0.190380  0.228906  0.417048  ...  0.143381  0.104080 -0.405662
175 -0.357893 -0.159158 -0.289425  ... -0.371118  0.579670 -0.413831
176  0.078708  0.165983  0.324744  ...  0.180002 -0.146310 -0.329281
177 -0.450046 -0.180979 -0.414211  ... -0.289672  0.616857 -0.062768
178  0.549715  0.408558 -0.055886  ... -0.170083 -0.294178  0.081205
179 -0.111201  0.472122 -0.075174  ... -0.518823  0.470020  0.047267
180  0.098447 -0.201907  0.119621  ...  0.019750 -0.268528 -0.056763
181  0.234285  0.144266  0.631389  ...  0.329869 -0.395606  0.139690
182  0.394321  0.239157 -0.043077  ...  0.423926 -0.695812  0.273296
183  0.634644  0.097258 -0.171962  ... -0.047281 -0.256005  0.162903
184  0.103204 -0.192399 -0.777966  ...  0.056135 -0.034793  0.034549
185  0.339759  0.239913  0.582344  ...  0.467792 -0.378750 -0.201036
186 -0.548353 -0.769797  0.067698  ...  0.085241  0.141845  0.210096
187 -0.167574  0.437010  0.178703  ...  0.036527  0.076168 -0.510175
188  0.048067 -0.586393  0.489235  ...  0.390122 -0.686588  0.234376
189  0.217725  0.049377 -0.477302  ...  0.089802  0.266892 -0.336807
190 -0.767265 -0.684753  0.213544  ... -0.010338  0.242734  0.254413
191 -0.428090 -0.898531  0.180227  ...  0.286884 -0.255007  0.141773
192  0.163057 -0.110622 -0.067697  ...  0.047667 -0.149770  0.577512
193 -0.174333 -0.612754  0.272226  ...  0.238010 -0.688222  0.725651
194  0.282385  0.153783 -0.218055  ... -0.519361 -0.136575  0.517739
195  0.533939  0.235234 -0.050181  ...  0.186320 -0.342353 -0.430962
196 -0.186149 -0.546681  0.344461  ...  0.130606 -0.057928 -0.451576
197  0.332607 -0.202328  0.220807  ...  1.000000 -0.718022 -0.250786
198 -0.334024  0.212138 -0.363419  ... -0.718022  1.000000 -0.193411
199 -0.167504 -0.265470  0.006970  ... -0.250786 -0.193411  1.000000

[200 rows x 200 columns]
# Transposing the dataframe calculates the correlations for each vector by making them the columns
```

It's also worth pointing out that if you use [`scipy.stats.spaermanr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html) the behavior is the same. It calculates correlations for the column vectors.